# Needing to set CLASSPATH well

Tags: java, path, classpath

I'm new in java and faced aproblem in PATH . I want to set classpath of java and want someone to review what i did to know what's the exact problem

java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_38"
JAVA(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java Hotspot(TM) Client VM (build 20.13-b02,mixed mode, sharing)
```

javac -version

```
javac 1.6.0_38
```

whereis java

```
/usr/bin/java  /etc/java  /usr/bin/X11/java   /usr/share/java
```

which java

```
/usr/bin/java
```

echo $CLASSPATH

```
empty
```

i edited in `/etc/profile` this

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

and i edited in `.bashrc` this

```
PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

I'm on ubuntu12.04

Comment: possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975684/setting-up-java-classpath-and-java-home-correctly-in-ubuntu

Comment: everyone has own setting and i think is not duplicate

Comment: A Question should contain an actual question, and this one doesn't.  Hint: "please review this" is NOT a question.  Hint 2: if you your current settings are not working, you need to explain what the symptoms are.

Comment: i explained it by echo #CLASSPATH is empty and post all my setting that help anyone have the knowledge to solve it

Comment: Why do you “Need to set `CLASSPATH`”? Java itself doesn’t need it. And since you have accepted an answer which makes no sense, it seems you have a working environment, even if the contents of the `CLASSPATH` is nonsense. Just a small hint: don’t trust twenty year old tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set CLASSPATH for java, DO :

1. Update .bashrc(sudo gedit $HOME/.bashrc)

   ```
        export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38
        export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
        export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```
2. now run this command to apply changes to .bashrc(source $HOME/.bashrc).close the terminal.
3. reopen the terminal

Comment: i'll try it now but am i delete the commands in /etc/profile or not ?

Comment: i tried your command sudo source $HOME/.bashrc but i got source : command not found

Comment: Sorry,there is no need to write sudo ...just write (source .bashrc)

Comment: Thanks for helping . i want to set CLASSPATH also because i echo $CLASSPATH and got empty !

Comment: you want CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/bin....am i right?...if yes then add in bashrc (export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin)

Comment: yes but how can i write it export CLASSPATH or what ?

Comment: i tried it but still empty when i used (echo $CLASSPATH)

Comment: have you run (source .bashrc) after updating .bashrc? also reopen terminal

Comment: yes i found it . sorry i didn't open new terminal +1 and accept answer

Comment: That will set `CLASSPATH` to the bin/ directory of the jdk, so it’s not empty, but it doesn’t make the slightest sense. In that directory are no classes.